# Is it appropriate to use footnotes in cover letters?

Tags: cover-letter

I am writing in my cover letter something in the lines of:

> I am applying for the `XXX` job offering as posted at `http://www.example.com/vacany`.

Is it appropriate or common to use a footnote, in order to format it like this?

> I am applying for the `XXX` job offering<sup>1</sup>
>
> <sup>1</sup>`http://www.example.com/vacany`

I am applying in Western Europe, in case it matters.

Comment: Honestly, I'd say the answer is just "No".

Comment: A  good tip is just **drastically shorten** links in email.  So:  "I am applying for the engineering job at example.com/vacancy123123."  Another tip is, the job will surely have a ID number.  "I'm applying for the plastics engineering position (reference 2871hg3)."

Comment: If they posted it, including a link to it seems a bit redundant.

Comment: As @Dukeling said, regardless of the general question you ask, what makes you think you need to include this information in the first place?

Comment: @Fattie there is no id, unfortunately, neither within the page nor in the url. It's just "Position X in our office in Y", both in the url and the page title.

Comment: @Lilienthal As a safeguard mostly, as it's my very first cover letter. :) I would agree though that it's redundant, given that I do describe the job vacancy in the letter and I will upload the documents directly at the respective page.

Comment: So, do not use a footnote.  If you have to include the full URL, so be it !  Good luck!

Comment: @Adama Understandable, but if you're applying directly to a position on an online portal, as is indeed often the case these days, it's completely unnecessary to reference an URL. Even if you weren't, mentioning the exact name of the position from the job ad would be enough. I can't currently think of a better example for use of footnotes in cover letters or I'd suggest changing it as the core question is still an interesting one, if hard to answer.

Comment: You should assume that the company knows for which jobs it's advertising, and in which way. If they don't supply an ID, assume the name (and perhaps the location) of the position is enough. If you really feel the need to indicate in your cover letter where you found the ad, say something like "online", "on your website", or "at XXX", where XXX is the name of the site hosting the ad.

Comment: I have been working since before offices had emails. Over that 30+ years I have received millions of emails. I have never once seen a footnote in an a email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

For one thing, you should generally avoid links in your cover letter. The correct way to refer to the position/advert is simply:

> the position of Top Dog at Alpha Kennels.

No links are needed at all - they've advertised the position; you're sending it to the specific contact listed in the ad; they should now what you're referring to. If you really insist on referring to the specific ad, leave it as:

> as advertised through Job Portal.

(or Newspaper, or whatever). No links.

**Footnotes in general**

Cover letters are not supposed to be academic essays - they need to encapsulate an introduction; your reasons for wanting the position; the reasons you believe you fit the position; and a reference to your included resume. In almost all circumstances, this can and should be done in no more than three paragraphs on a single page.

It is possible for someone reviewing applications to see hundreds of such cover letters for only one opening. At the very least, they will likely have to view dozens. They don't want to spend a lot of time reading your cover letter or following footnotes and references.

Answer (score 0):

You can put footnotes in your cover letter and your resume, but I don't think you need it in this case.

Just tell them the name of the website. I found this job posted at "Acme Jobs" or whatever it's called. If you're not sure of the site name, "acmejobs.com" is fine. It doesn't need a footnote.